# Validation for entered string in Edit Box in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have created a user login Dialog Box in MFC, which have two edit fields, for username & password respectively. I need to restrict/disable user from typing "space" & a few "special characters" in Login/Password Edit Box fields. Please help me with this. Thank you.

EDIT: I'm validating the Username & Password with my SQLite database. Everything is working fine. Additional requirement is to restrict user from typing spaces in the edit field.
Please explain with some simple example. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subclass(Inherit) the CEdit control of MFC and  override PreTranslateMessage and handle WM_CHAR message and filter the characters there

```
BOOL CMyEditBox::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    int  nTextLength = this->GetWindowTextLength();
    if(pMsg->message==WM_CHAR)
    {
       // Ignoring 0 to 9
       if( ( pMsg->wParam >= '0' &&   pMsg->wParam <= '9' ) )
       {
            return true;
       }
    }
    return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: @ Jeeva Can you explain with example please.

Comment: I'm not getting 'PreTranslateMessage' in Messages, I'm getting only a few messages like EN_CHANGE, EN_ERRSPACE, EN_KILLFOCUS, etc. Any reason? I'm struck with this.

Comment: Rahul, you need to inherit your own class from CEdit. And inside that you can override  PreTanslateMessage

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/NumEditCtl.aspx use this as a reference for creating custom control and validation. for more complex example refer http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/validatingedit.aspx

Comment: @Jeeva, we can still enter numbers from number pad, use condition as: 
if ((pMsg->wParam >= '0') && (pMsg->wParam <= '9') || (pMsg->wParam >= VK_NUMPAD0) && (pMsg->wParam <= VK_NUMPAD9)) return TURE;

Answer (score 1):

Handle the edit-control change in `EN_CHANGE` notification message.

Comment: @ Ajay Can you explain with example please.

Comment: If you are using dialog-editor, you can: select the edit-control of your choice, select "Control Events", and then select EN_CHANGE. It will put some code in CPP/Header files.

Comment: @ Ajay Thanks for your reply. Yes I did get some function added to my Login.cpp file. How should I proceed from here.

Comment: Use GetDlgItemText(id-of-edit-control) to get the text and process appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.flounder.com/validating_edit_control.htm.
It has an explanation plus sample code

**EDIT**
By the way, I'm not sure that "live validation" for a password field is a good idea. I think "lazy validation" is a better solution here.

Answer (score 0):

As per above answer, this works fine but you can also override CEdit with ASCII values,(in this case we used HEX values followed by '\x')

```
BOOL TestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if(pMsg->message==WM_CHAR)
    {
       if( ( pMsg->wParam >= '\x20'  &&   pMsg->wParam <= '\x2D'))
       {
            return true;
       }
    }
    return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```